# Build JSON with dynamic property name

Tags: groovy

I practice with Groovy and yesterday I found some code:

```
def result = report.data.rows.collectMany{
            [headers, it.metrics[0].values].transpose().collect{ h, v ->
                [
                 metric_name: h.name,
                 metric_value: v,
                 report_date: it.dimensions[0],
                 user_type: it.dimensions[1]
                ]
            }
        }
```

Now I want to use dynamic property name from variable instead of `user_type`, I add this line:

```
String attr = ff.getAttribute("unique_dim");
...
report_date: it.dimensions[0],
attr: it.dimensions[1]
```

How can I call variable attr from this line `attr: it.dimensions[1]`, not just a String "attr"? It's a dynamic variable, and in this example it will build JSON with property name `attr`, but I want to get variable content as property name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To evaluate a map key as a variable, you place it in parentheses:

```
report_date: it.dimensions[0],
(attr): it.dimensions[1]
```